# POST login with xcode

Tags: php, xcode, post, authentication

I want to change my code to auto-login the user when he uses the app. 
Currently my code is :

```
NSString *identifiant = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identifiant"];
NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Password"];
if((identifiant) && (password))
{
    //Configure URL
    NSString* host = @"http://www.example.com";
    NSString* complement = @"/account/login";



    NSString* user_name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Identifiant"];
    NSString* password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Password"];
    //Add URL + Folder
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", host, complement];


    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


    //NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Add some informations POST
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_name=%@&password=%@&submit=submit", user_name, password];;


    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];



    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) [_loadscreen loadRequest:request];
         else if (error != nil) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
else
{


UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It's work with this code, but I haven't error message when the user isn't connected or when his IDs are incorrect. 
Can we update this code, change to better code, using post connexion because in my php system I check if post is submit.